# If your img tag is automatically generated during runtime can you change the src using JQuery/JScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an html page that doesn't contain an image until the page actually loads, and then once you inspect the source you see:

```
<img src="http://s5.parature.com//ics/cm/images/bt/button2_online.gif" class="available" alt="Chat Help is available" title="Chat Help is available" style="border: medium none">
```

I'd like to try and change the img src from what it is, to the same thing but make it https. I added my javascript AFTER this displays but it doesn't work and I'm not sure if it's supposed to or if it's even possible. Actually I'm using JQuery.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$("#available").attr('src', 'https://s5.parature.com//ics/cm/images/bt/button2_online.gif');
</script></div>
```

The code that actually calls the img and places it into the html at run time is this:

```
<a id="b2b8839e-6318-4c34-9863-9071b06192f3" href="javascript:void(0);"  onclick="return launchChatWindow('https://com.parature.com/ics/support/default.asp?deptID=15028&task=chat&deploymentId=b2b8839e-6318-4c34-9863-9071b06192f3');"></a>
<script src="https://de.com.edu/js/chatDeployment.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = createDplOnLoadDelegate('b2b8839e-6318-4c34-9863-9071b06192f3', 'com.parature.com', 15026, 15028, window.onload, true);


</script>
```

But that's all I have access to since the img is called/generated at run.

Comment: You probably just need to wrap you code in a `$( document ).ready(function(){ //stuff here });` so it doesn't run until after the page has rendered

Comment: How does the image load in the first place after the page loads?  Can you just change it when it loads?

Comment: It's called by something else in the code. I'm modifying a login page for something I support. So the login page itself doesn't have the code, it's called from a remote resource from the company(Parature). If that makes sense. I'll add the code to the question.

Comment: If you are doing this to avoid an ssl warning, it's not going to work (you will still get the warning)

Answer (score 0):

`$("#available")` is incorrect. 
the wildcard "`#`" refers to the "id" attribute, while "`.`" refers to a class. 
The "`id`" attribute makes the only element, so "`class`" is used for multiple elements. 
Your condigo would like this: `$(".available")...`